# htaccess - how to rewrite rule for lower and uppercase urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-index

i have following .htaccess, i am getting double urls in google....i have tried some codes in order to block uppercase urls....but nothing works for me...

example of double urls

```
/Come.php
/come.php
```

my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^my/shop/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /my/shop/shop.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^my/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /my/brand/brand.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^my/social-share/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /my/social-share/share.php?shareid=$1

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.myweb.co.uk/404.php
```

i have no idea how to block uppercase urls..

thanks for your help.

Comment: Why block them?  This is what canonical urls are for: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^my/shop/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /my/shop/shop.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^my/brand/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /my/brand/brand.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^my/social-share/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /my/social-share/share.php?shareid=$1

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.myweb.co.uk/404.php
```

Just remove the A-Z in each query...Then the regex won't match on it.